# emit every document in the database with lucene

Tags: lucene, scoring

I've got an index where I need to get *all* documents with a standard search, still ranked by relevance, even if a document isn't a hit.

My first idea is to add a field that is always matched, but that might deform the relevance score.

Comment: could you clarify if you need all the documents ordered by some measure? If so, you could open the index using IndexReader and loop through the documents collection.

Comment: In Solr you could use a query of "*:*" to retrieve all documents & all fields from the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `BooleanQuery` to combine your original query with a `MatchAllDocsQuery`. You can mitigate the effect this has on scoring by setting the boost on the `MatchAllDocsQuery` to zero before you combine it with your main query. This way you don't have to add an otherwise bogus field to the index.

For example:

```
// Parse a query by the user.
QueryParser qp = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_35, "text", new StandardAnalyzer());
Query standardQuery = qp.parse("User query may go here");

// Make a query that matches everything, but has no boost.
MatchAllDocsQuery matchAllDocsQuery = new MatchAllDocsQuery();
matchAllDocsQuery.setBoost(0f);

// Combine the queries.
BooleanQuery boolQuery = new BooleanQuery();
boolQuery.add(standardQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
boolQuery.add(matchAllDocsQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

// Now just pass it to the searcher.
```

This should give you hits from `standardQuery` followed by the rest of the documents in the index.